# Relaunching explorer with taskbar

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

If you terminate `explorer.exe` which is also hosting a taskbar system component and then launch it again from task manager, it will open itself again with taskbar fully functional.

However, if I set up my own shell program, instead of explorer (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon), re-logon, and then terminate it from `Task manager`, and execute `explorer.exe` it gives me nothing but explorer window(file manager). Taskbar component does not show itself.

How can I achieve this? I am developing a kiosk application and I want to give administrators rights to switch to classic desktop if they need it. However, executing `explorer.exe` does not work like I expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

[This Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/372975/restarting-explorer-does-not-restore-taskbar) sounds like you need to launch "C:\Windows\Explorer.exe" instead of just "Explorer.exe" to get the taskbar back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as well. Strange. I'll try to test it with this GUID parameter.

Comment: No, this does not work. But i found something odd. If i logon remotely as another user, and i change shell to explorer in registry (!) - i can terminate explorer and execute it again - i will get a taskbar. Now, i change (without logging out) default shell in registry to my app. Now i terminate explorer.exe from user session and execute it again - taskbat won't appear. Odd. Looks like explorer checks if it's default shell in registry, and basing on this setting decides if taskbar is needed.